# How to send http post request from Android?

Tags: android, http-post

I'm new to android and now I'm so tired of searching the best tutorial about android HTTP requests.

I'm trying to send these parameters to phpServer,

- Name = "some name"
- email = "some email"

Can we do this in MainActivity.java file? is this need any jar(library) file?
any suggestions are welcome.

I tried this,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == btnSubscribe){
        HttpURLConnection client = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www/somewebsite.com/API/SUBSCRIBE");
            client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            client.setRequestMethod("POST");
            client.setRequestProperty("name","test one");
            client.setRequestProperty("email","text@gmail.com");
            client.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream outputPost = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            outputPost.flush();
            outputPost.close();
            client.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

        } catch(MalformedURLException error) {
            showError("Handles an incorrectly entered UR");
        }
        catch(SocketTimeoutException error) {
            showError("Handles URL access timeout");
        }
        catch (IOException error) {
            showError("Handles input and output errors");
        }finally {
            if(client != null)
            client.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sahan Go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya sorry I cleared all codes because not worked for me. Now I'm in a new project.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya guys can you take a look at now? I tried this.

Comment: `name` should be `Name`

Comment: I think it's not a problem here. @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using this code and working as well. Try this code.

```
public static String httpPostRequest(Context context, String url, String email) {
        String response = "";
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            LogUtils.d("RequestManager", url + " ");
            LogUtils.e("data::", " " + data);
            URL urlObj = new URL(url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Email", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8");


            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            LogUtils.d("post response code", conn.getResponseCode() + " ");

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();



            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            response = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LogUtils.d("Error", "error");
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        LogUtils.d("RESPONSE POST", response);
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the most httpClint is deprecated now so if you can now use httpUrlConnection for the same.

you can refer to
[here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

and if you want to use library then you can use

- [VOLLEY](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)
- [RETROFIT](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

These two are the best library.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm Jitendra ramoliya's answer is correct though it did not specify what 'data' is.

data there is a string where the first encoded value is the POST index and the second one is that index's value, separated by an '='.

This was not obvious at first and android documentation does not cover the data concatenation.

`$_POST['Email']` is equivalent to `URLEncoder.encode("Email", "UTF-8")` with this method | and to add its value is

```
URLEncoder.encode("Email", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8")
```